# MongoDB and visual C++ 2008 linker errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mongodb

i'm trying to get the c++ client for mongodb working in visual studio 2008. i can reference the includes, but whenever i tell the linker about the mongodb .lib file i get the following error: "fatal error LNK1257: code generation failed". if visual studio can't find the .lib, then i get a bunch of unresolved externals errors. i'm really pretty lost at this point.

Comment: Are there any other errors before that? It's usually accompanied by some other errors...

Comment: I've just cloned MongoDB from github. I get the impression that a Boost dependency is missing? Here's a link to a screen grab: http://files.getdropbox.com/u/404755/capture.png

Comment: And here's an explanation: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Building+for+Windows regarding prerequisites and dependencies.

RTFM Ed!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the latest from [GitHub](http://github.com/mongodb/mongo/tree/master)?

Have you installed vs 2008 SP1?